# Indent text and put label in the indent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

The context of what I am doing is formatting a number of prayers.  What is needed is to have the text indented a little and in the space created by that indent put a label indicating who is supposed to be saying it.  So what I would like is a command like this:

```
\prayer{V.}{In nomine Patris et Filii et Spiritus Sancti.}
\prayer{R.}{Amen.}
```

Sometimes the labels are longer, but never more then 3-4 characters.

What I have so far is this, which indents the text, I just have no idea how to get the label where I want it.

```
\newcommand*{\prayer}[2]{\begin{addmargin}[3em]{0em}#2\end{addmargin}}
```

Is there any simple solution to what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options, depending on the indentation alignment/wrapping you're after:

1. Using [`changepage`](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage):

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{changepage}

   \newcommand{\prayer}[3][4em]{%
     \begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{0pt}
       \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{\bfseries #2}}%
       \ignorespaces #3
     \end{adjustwidth}
   }

   \begin{document}

   \prayer{V.}{In nomine Patris et Filii et Spiritus Sancti.}
   \prayer{R.}{Amen.}

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec purus euismod justo 
   dapibus interdum. Quisque non euismod dui. Aenean ornare eleifend libero at condimentum. 
   Aliquam sed tellus vel magna imperdiet placerat in vel massa. Suspendisse gravida felis 
   in maximus commodo. Donec pellentesque auctor suscipit. Proin tempus massa ut est accumsan 
   porta. Quisque pulvinar est ac faucibus iaculis. Integer eget urna dapibus, sodales nisi 
   eget, tincidunt leo. Vivamus quis gravida eros. Donec finibus eros leo, at posuere orci 
   euismod eu. Integer a varius dui. Aliquam tincidunt, elit sed condimentum gravida, tortor 
   leo vulputate nibh, ut sagittis mauris risus et metus. Sed nec faucibus tortor, non 
   pulvinar lectus.

   \prayer{V.}{In nomine Patris et Filii et Spiritus Sancti.}
   \prayer{ABCD.}{%
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec purus euismod justo 
     dapibus interdum. Quisque non euismod dui. Aenean ornare eleifend libero at condimentum.}
   \prayer{R.}{Amen.}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Using `\makebox`:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \renewcommand{\prayer}[3][4em]{%
     \par\noindent
     \makebox[#1][l]{\bfseries #2}%
     #3%
   }

   \begin{document}

   \prayer{V.}{In nomine Patris et Filii et Spiritus Sancti.}
   \prayer{R.}{Amen.}

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec purus euismod justo 
   dapibus interdum. Quisque non euismod dui. Aenean ornare eleifend libero at condimentum. 
   Aliquam sed tellus vel magna imperdiet placerat in vel massa. Suspendisse gravida felis 
   in maximus commodo. Donec pellentesque auctor suscipit. Proin tempus massa ut est accumsan 
   porta. Quisque pulvinar est ac faucibus iaculis. Integer eget urna dapibus, sodales nisi 
   eget, tincidunt leo. Vivamus quis gravida eros. Donec finibus eros leo, at posuere orci 
   euismod eu. Integer a varius dui. Aliquam tincidunt, elit sed condimentum gravida, tortor 
   leo vulputate nibh, ut sagittis mauris risus et metus. Sed nec faucibus tortor, non 
   pulvinar lectus.

   \prayer{V.}{In nomine Patris et Filii et Spiritus Sancti.}
   \prayer{ABCD.}{%
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec purus euismod justo 
     dapibus interdum. Quisque non euismod dui. Aenean ornare eleifend libero at condimentum.}
   \prayer{R.}{Amen.}

   \end{document}
   ```